# pytorch model can read succes on local envi(windows,pycharm) but fail on server(unix)

Tags: pytorch

[I can load model on local(window, pycharm) successfully, but it fail on server(unix) with the same code.][1]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inference.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()
  File "inference.py", line 82, in main
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(config.ESIM_MODEL_PATH))
  File "/home/ai-center/yangyitai/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 587, in load
    with _open_zipfile_reader(opened_file) as opened_zipfile:
  File "/home/ai-center/yangyitai/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 242, in __init__
    super(_open_zipfile_reader, self).__init__(torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(name_or_buffer))
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:145] . PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: not a ZIP archive
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but the error is incomplete. Could you please check whether you've posted the full error? That will help to solve the issue.

Comment: no, I did not posted all info because I don't know how to edit my question. Wait a moment, I try it once again